# kendo grid sorting not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sorting, firefox, kendo-grid, cyrillic

I have problem with sorting in Kendo grid. Here is my example: http://dojo.telerik.com/iVATi 
In IE sorting works fine: **default view** and **asc sorting view** are the same: first going elements starting with symbols, second elements with a-z letters, third elements with а-я letters.
 But in Chrome and Firefox I see three other results:
1). default view: first going element starting with symbols, second elements with a-z letters, third elements with а-я letters. (correct!)
2). asc sorting: first going elements starting with symbols, second elements with а-я letters, third elements with a-z letters. (bad!)
3). desc sorting: first going elements with z-a letters, second elements with я-а letters, third sorted elements with symbols. (correct!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by Chrome's unstable sorting and [adding an auxiliary data field](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/stable-sort-chrome) is the standard way to resolve this limitation.

In case you don't want to add indexes in the data items array, it is also possible to add them on the fly with [`schema.parse`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse):

```
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
      { Name: "!asdgad" },
      { Name: "@sgjkhsh" },
      { Name: "adfadfka" },
      { Name: "tgjbndgnb" },
      { Name: "xsdfvks" },
      { Name: "абдваолптрв" },
      { Name: "пролрлитс" },
      { Name: "юатроваро" },
      { Name: "юдвлоитвт" }
    ],
    schema: {
      parse: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          data[i].index = i;
        }
        return data;
      }
    }
  });
```

You will still need to use a custom comparer function though.

Comment: And what about this solution: [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/iVATi/3) ?

Comment: This doesn't sort properly on my side. Try using this approach with the Address column here, the Names will still shift - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/stable-sort-chrome

Comment: Yes, this link with idea of adding positions I used initially. And [http://dojo.telerik.com/UKimo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UKimo) with compare function `compare: function(a, b){
             return a.index - b.index;
           }` works fine the same as in IE.

Comment: data: [
          { Name: "1" },
          { Name: "2" },
          { Name: "5" },
          { Name: "10" },
          { Name: "20" }
        ]  Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I extended sorted datasource with index field and added comparer-function by index for field name:
http://dojo.telerik.com/UKimo
May be exists other solutions?